# Is an object function executed with each method call?

Tags: javascript

In this:

```
somefunction = function() {

    somefunction.method = function() {
         //stuff
    }
//other stuff
}
```

Is `somefunction` executed everytime `somefunction.method` is?

Comment: Oh the closures.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/1331430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, somefunction is executed when you have any of these lines:

```
somefunction()
somefunction.call()
somefunction.apply()
new somefunction;
```

`somefunction.method()` will only execute `somefunction.method`, but that will have access to variables in the scope of `somefunction` (as well as its own local variables and all global variables of course).

Answer (score 0):

Not inherently (unless it is explicitly invoked in the "other stuff").  It is *evaluated*, but that is only CPU time and not enough to matter.

Comment: What do you mean by evaluated?  You mean it's checked for errors?

Comment: @PitaJ: The expression `somefunction` is evaluated. This involves searching for the binding of `somefunction` in all applicable scopes. The function is not invoked.

Answer (score 0):

No. However you are creating a new closure each time somefunction is called. If somefunction relies on any variables outside of its scope, then the somefunction.method may change depending on when somefunction is called, thus creating a race condition (never fun to debug).

This is probably not the right way to approach the problem.

Consider

```
somefunction = function() {
  // constructor
}


somefunction.prototype.method = function() {
  //stuff
}
```

Comment: You mean `somefunction.prototype.method = function() { }` :)

Comment: whups... quite right, edited... I should never drink and code :)